# Image is rotated when reading from byte in Django InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: django, numpy, python-imaging-library, byte, opencv, python

I'm using Django ImageField for user to upload image. I want to read the image directly from InMemoryUploadedFile byte to ndarray for processing. However, some of the images that appeared upright in my folder will be rotated. My images are all mobile phone camera photos. I suspect it is because of the exif info that cause the rotation.

I checked the exif info and it shows <Orientation.LEFT_BOTTOM: 8>. This is same as what I get as the image is rotated 270 degree counter-clockwise. Is there anyway I can read the image from byte to ndarray in upright orientation as per what I see in file explorer?

Below is how I read the image in view.py

```
upload_file_1 = request.FILES.get('image1', None)
image_1 = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(upload_file_1.file.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

p/s: I don't want to save the raw upload image to media folder before postprocessing.